# Why is there both a create_user and a _create_user method in django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager

Tags: python, django

In the [source for django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/models/), there is a UserManager class whose job (as far as I understand) is to create users according to a number of received parameters and save them to the database. The class accomplishes this with the use of two methods. One method `create_user` and one method `_create_user`, the latter is called by the former. My question is, why the need for two methods? Why not simply have one that does the exact same thing? Like this:

```
def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None,
                 **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
    """
    now = timezone.now()
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                      is_staff=False, is_active=True,
                      is_superuser=False,
                      date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found out the answer on my own. The class also has a `create_superuser` method that calls `_create_user` as well, but with different arguments. The use of `_create_user` thus spares us from having to write the same functionality twice.

Comment: Also, having an underscore at the start of the name indicates that it is an internal method, so as an external user of the object, you should be ignoring it. This is a reasonably common pattern - an internal method (with an underscore at the start) that does the heavy lifting for an external method, and which can be reused by other external methods.